# On an 8x8 board, a knight is on the second square of the last row. Only moving upwards, how many routes to the top?

Tags: mathematics, combinatorics, chess, knight-moves

In chess, a knight moves in L-shaped jumps consisting of two squares along a row or column plus one square at a right angle. If it can only move *up* the board, how many routes can it take to reach any square on the top row of the board?

Comment: So the knight starts where it usually starts, and you want the number of ways it can reach the top row?

Comment: Yes, the knight starts at the second square of the bottom row and all the ways it can reach the top row. Thanks.

Answer (score 17):

The easiest way to do this, I think, is

> just to fill in the number of routes from the top row (where the number is already 1: you're on the top row and there's only one way to get to the top row, namely by making no moves) downward: at each stage, you put in each square the sum of the numbers in the squares you can move to from there. It's quicker and more reliable to do it with a computer, but it's well within the range of reasonable hand calculation.

The answer is

> 269

and here are the calculations:

> `1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
>     1   1   2   2   2   2   1   1
>     3   4   5   5   5   5   4   3
>     6   8  11  13  13  11   8   6
>    15  21  28  29  29  28  21  15
>    36  46  65  73  73  65  46  36
>    86 116 159 168 168 159 116  86
>   205 269 373 413 413 373 269 205`

Comment: I think the second row should contain digits 2 and 4. Oh, but wait...

Comment: In the calculation diagram, each number seems to be roughly 2.5 times the one above it, maybe just a little less. Do you think there's some definite value the ratio might be approaching, given a larger board?

Comment: Yes, there will certainly be some such value. If we represent two successive rows by an 8-element vector (we only need 8 elements, not 16, because of symmetry) then moving down one row is achieved by multiplying that vector by a certain 8x8 matrix. Then, barring improbable coincidences, everything will grow at a rate given by the largest eigenvalue of that matrix.

Comment: Oh, I realise that that assumes the board is only getting larger in one dimension, so it's 8xn and n is increasing. If we consider an nxn board, I bet some limit-y thing is still true, but it's not so straightforward.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan If you ignore the edge effects, each row is twice the sum of the previous two rows. That's a recusive relation with growth factor $1+\sqrt{3}$. So that will be the approximate growth factor near the middle of the board.

Comment: I agree with the heuristic, but (1) it's not obvious that you _can_ ignore the edge effects (is it?) and (2) the not-so-heuristic argument I mentioned above doesn't, so far as I currently see, work for the limit of large _square_ boards.

Comment: If my calculations are correct (which they _might_ be), then for an 8-wide board the actual ratio approaches a root of a degree-7 polynomial which is approximately 2.39, versus 1+sqrt(3) ~= 2.73. Numerical experimentation suggests that for the limit of large square boards the edge effects _do_ go away and you get 1+sqrt(3).

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan I wonder what made you came back to this 4-year-old question. But great addition nonetheless! For reference the transition matrix is: $\left(\begin{array}{cccccccc}0&0&1&0&0&1&0&0\\0&0&0&1&1&0&1&0\\1&0&0&0&0&1&0&1\\0&1&0&0&0&0&1&0\\1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0&0&0&0&0\\0&0&1&0&0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&1&0&0&0&0\end{array}\right)$ (first four element is the next row, last four element is the current row). Src: `\left(\begin{array}{cccccccc}0&0&1&0&0&1&0&0\\0&0&0&1&1&0&1&0\\1&0&0&0&0&1&0&1\\0&1&0&0&0&0&1&0\\1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0&0&0&0&0\\0&0&1&0&0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&1&0&0&0&0\end{array}\right)`

Comment: I came back to it because someone posted an exact duplicate of it because they didn't find my answer clear enough. (They didn't comment here because they didn't have enough rep. They didn't explain in the question why they were asking it because, er, they didn't feel like it, I guess?)